# Delete filtered rows in a table

Tags: excel, vba

In an autofiltered view if i need to delete filtered rows, i do it with

```
Sub deleteFiltered()
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
End Sub
```

and it works like i expect.

But i even realized that this doesn't work, if i deal with a "real" table. How is it possible to delete filtered rows in a table?

Comment: You need to filter the listobjects.databodyrange.

Comment: @JvdV do you have an example?

Comment: Sure, I have added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this table, as a [`ListObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject).

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Sample Code:</sub>***

```
Sub DeleteFilteredRows()
    With Sheet1 'Change according to your own sheets CodeName
        With .ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange 'Change to name of your table
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="B" 'Sample filter applied
            .EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]